# How to get the filter results in rest api

Tags: python, rest, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm new to python and Jira rest api. I need to know how to export the results to excel(in the same format how we get it manually).

```
import jira.client
from jira.client import JIRA
options = {'server': 'https"//atlassian.com'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('ss' , 'ss')
issues = jira.attachment('filterid')
```

However, it fails to export anything. Help me out

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how to turn issues to an excel object.

First, there is no way to export excel from Jira directly according to its documentation.
Here is link for you. https://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Second, you need to use some extra modules to turn the `attachment` object into excel. Like xlrd/xlwt. Here is link for you.

https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966
https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966

Hope this helps.